# Shell Script Json, Mac

Tags: json, macos, shell, terminal

Here is my code

```
function poke() {

    json="curl -s -X GET http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/bug.json";
    prop="half_damage_to"
    temp=echo $json | sed 's/\\\\\//\//g' | sed 's/[{}]//g' | awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | sed 's/\"\:\"/\|/g' | sed 's/[\,]/ /g' | sed 's/\"//g' | grep -w $prop
    echo ${temp##*|}
}
```

The problem here is that the terminal is only printing out the first JSON item, `half_damage_to:[name|fighting` when it should be printing them all. How exactly do I get it to print all items in the JSON dictionary that are within `half_damage_to`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `extended-regexp(grep -E)` to match on `half_damage_to` array and then use `awk` to split on `half_damage_to`

```
curl -s -X GET http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/bug.json |  grep -oE '"half_damage_to":\[{.*?\}]' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="half_damage_to\":"} {print $2}'
```

Output:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"fighting",
      "url":"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/2.json"
   },
   {  
      "name":"flying",
      "url":"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/3.json"
   },
   {  
      "name":"poison",
      "url":"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4.json"
   },
   {  
      "name":"ghost",
      "url":"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/8.json"
   },
   {  
      "name":"steel",
      "url":"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/9.json"
   },
   {  
      "name":"fire",
      "url":"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/10.json"
   },
   {  
      "name":"fairy",
      "url":"http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/18.json"
   }
]
```